# ¿Por qué un usuario puede modificar el perfil de cualquier otro?

Tags: php

Quiero que un usuario no pueda editar el perfil de otro.
Tengo un script llamado "login.php" y otro llamado "login-controller.php", el primer archivo recoge los datos otorgados por el usuario y posteriormente, el segundo script inicia una sesión y redirige al usuario a su página de perfil utilizando `header("profile.php?username=".$u."")`.

Hasta aquí todo bien pero, desde este punto si accedo al perfil de otro usuario por la url, puedo editar su perfil también.

En el archivo profile.php incluí el siguiente código para intentar que solamente pueda editar el usuario al que le pertenece el perfil utilizando la sesión creada, pero, únicamente no muestra el botón cuando no se ha iniciado la variable de sesión:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if($_SESSION["username"]){
        echo '<div class="edit-profile"><form method="POST" action="edit-profile.php"><input type="submit" value="Edit Profile"></form></div>';
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Nunca prueba si el usario que ve la página es es el dueño del perfil, solamente si el usario esté autenticado.

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo realizar esta comprobación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si validas por el **`username`**, podría suceder que exista 2 usuarios con el mismo **`username`** y los dos tengan acceso en sus perfiles ingresando mediante la misma URL. Tendrías que validarlo por el **`id`** del usuario, ya que su **`id`** sería **primary key** y éstas **`id`** serán únicas por cada usuario.

También tendrías que enviar como **`$_SESSION`** al **`id`** del usuario y verificar si la **`id`** con la que ingresó coincide con la **`id`** que recibe como parámetro de la URL.

En tu header, deberías enviar como parámetro el **`id`**:

```
header("profile.php?id=".$id."")
```

Luego tendrías que recoger el parámetro de la URL de la siguiente forma:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Y con la variable obtenida, tendrías que validarlo en tu **`$_SESSION`**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id = $_GET['id']; //obtengo el id
    if($_SESSION["id"] == $id){ //si la id obtenida es igual a la id con la que inicié sesión, entro al if
        echo '<div class="edit-profile"><form method="POST" action="edit-profile.php"><input type="submit" value="Edit Profile"></form></div>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Soy consciente, cree un formulario de registro que impida que existan dos usuarios con el mismo nombre pero, si puede ser peor y puedes explicarme el por qué estaría agradecido.

Comment: Ah claro, también vendría bien eso, validar si el usuario existe e impedir que se cree el mismo usuario, pero lo más recomendable sería validar por su primary key (id) ya que estos nunca se repiten y ya no sería necesario darle lógica de verificar si el usuario existe.

Comment: En eso tienes toda la razón, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Sabiendo que la redirección está preconfigurada en el archivo "login-controller.php" de esta forma: `header("profile.php?username=".$u."")`

En el archivo "profile.php" creo una variable donde almacenar el nombre de usuario dado por la URL desde "login-controller.php" para posteriormente comprobar si le pertenece a este usuario.

> $u = $_GET['username'];

Para ejecutar este código también se debe comprobar primero si existe una sesión, independientemente del usuario que sea.

Quedando el código:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $u = $_GET['username'];
    if($_SESSION){
        if($_SESSION["username"] == $u){
        echo '<div class="edit-profile">
                <form method="POST" action="edit-profile.php">
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit Profile">
                </form>
            </div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Ahora solamente podrá modificar este perfil el usuario que tenga una sesión que coincida con su nombre.